# (jQuery) How do I find the first link which has a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a link **somewhere** (not predetermined) down the tree like this:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div>
    <div>
      <a href="asdf.com">link</a>
      <a href="#bar" class="specialLink">link</a>
      <a href="#bar2" class="specialLink">link</a>
      <a href="#bar3" class="specialLink">link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about selecting the first link with the class "specialLink" using .find()?

My non working guess is:

```
$("#foo").find(".specialLink a:first")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use one combined selector, like this:

```
$("#foo a.specialLink:first")
```

Or like your original:

```
$("#foo").find("a.specialLink:first")
```

Previously it was looking for the first `<a>` that was a *descendant* of a `.specialLink`, rather than the same element.

Comment: duho! I knew it was something easy. Just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector would be:

```
$("#foo").find("a.specialLink:first");
```

Better yet, save a few function calls by using:

```
$("$foo a.specialLink:first");
```

Answer (score 0):

`.specialLink` is the a itself. With a (space) `:first` you will be looking for childeren of `.specialLink`.

```
$("#foo").find("a.specialLink:first")
```